# Rocksaw JNI_Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rocksaw in java.library.path

Tags: java, netbeans, java-native-interface

I installed Visual C ++.Add maven on Netbean

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mlaccetti</groupId>
            <artifactId>rocksaw</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I run the program

```
  InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("www.microsoft.com");

        RawSocket socket = new RawSocket();
        socket.bind(inetAddress);
        System.out.println(socket.isOpen());
```

I always get the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rocksaw in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at www.NewClass1.main(NewClass1.java:23)
```

Need to generate dll but when I try to compile I get error.
I use: window 7 32bit,netbean.

```
cd C:\Users\NoFear\Downloads\rocksaw-1.0.3\src\jni
g++ -c -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\include\win32" -c RawSocket.c -o RawSocket.o
```

ERROR............................

I have never done JNI before so please help me on how to fix it

Comment: Did you download the DLL for the library as well?

Comment: @m0skit0 I can't find rocksaw dll file

Comment: What error you get when trying to compile? Why you just don't use Java? It is not the right tool for your earlier question.

Comment: @TouyaAkira I don't think Java is the right tool for this, but did you check this other library? – m0skit0=>Because before that you said.And https://www.mylanviewer.com/socks-scanner.html=>they may scan 10,000 IP addresses per second.I cannot get that speed with a regular java socket.Maybe my compilation is incorrect since I'm learning it the first time

Comment: That site probably uses nmap or masscan behind as a service. Again, I don't think Java is the right tool for your problem. You're trying to do a surgery operation with a hammer. Each tool fits for a specific set of problems, and for your problem, Java is the wrong tool.

Comment: This is a difficult problem. Maybe I need a lot of time to find a suitable solution. Thanks for your help: D

Comment: @m0skit0 I missed your answer, fortunately I reread it carefully.I feel masscan is right for me